# Pass span value to a hidden input

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My span is a dynamic value (integer). I need to pass the value that is apearing in span to my input.

This should be possible with jquery but i don't know how.

```html
<span class="id-label"></span>
<input type="hidden" id="label" name="label" value="" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  
  $('#example tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.id-label').text($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
      $('#classModal').modal('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: At the point in the code where you set the text of the `span`, set the `value` in the `input`

Comment: What you said looks very simple but i couldn't understand it. The value showing in span is an id selected from a table.

Comment: You stated that the integer value is dynamically added to the `span`. At the exact same point in your code that sets the text of the span, set the value in the `input`. If you need help doing this, please show the code which is setting the `span` value.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. For future reference you should edit the question to include the code. I've done it for you in this instance. I've also added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code in the question you're retrieving a value and setting it as the `text()` of the `.id-label`, you can use the same value and set it as the `val()` of your target input:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  
  $('#example tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
    let $tr = $(this);

    if ($tr.hasClass('selected')) {
      $tr.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $tr.addClass('selected');
      $('#classModal').modal('hide');

      let targetValue = $tr.find('td:first').text();
      $('.id-label').text(targetValue);
      $('#label').val(targetValue);
    }
  });
});
```

Note that I removed `.closest('tr')` as `this` refers to the `tr` already.